# how to convert time string '11:23 p.m.' time '23:23'

Tags: mysql

Hello MySQL and PHP developers,

Is there any predefined function from MySQL to convert time string '11:23 p.m.' to '23:23'.

I have tried `select DATE_FORMAT('2015-05-22 06:45:23', '%H:%i %p')` which gave me this result: 
`06:45 AM`

But in my case I have string `11:23 p.m.` in my time field which is of varchar type. 
Is there anyway to convert `11:23 p.m.` to `23:23` in MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is `p.m` you need to replace `.` before using any conversion. Here is a way

```
mysql> select date_format(str_to_date(replace('11:23 p.m','.',''),'%h:%i %p'),'%H:%i') as time ;
+-------+
| time  |
+-------+
| 23:23 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```